# How to optimize following python code for given equation?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, computation

[image: for the following equation,python code needs to be optimized. By considering random initialization of variables]

I wrote following python code but it's taking too much time to execute, is it possible to write the code with minimum number of for loops?

```py
import numpy as np

N=10
K=3
D=4
M_ikl = np.zeros((N,K,D))
one_minu_theta = np.random.randint(5, size=(N,D))+0.5
F = np.random.randint(2, size=(K,D))+0.5
sigma = np.random.randint(2, size=(K,D))+0.5
dat = np.random.randint(2, size=(N,D))+0.5
tau = np.random.randint(2, size=(K,D))+0.5
exp_gamma = np.random.randint(2, size=(K))+0.5
exp_gamma_minus = np.random.randint(2, size=(K))+0.5    

M_ikl = np.zeros((N,K,D))
for i in range(N):
    for k in range(K):
        for l in range(D):
            M_ikl[i][k][l] = np.exp(one_minu_theta[i][l]*(F[k][l]+(sigma[k][l]-1)*np.log(dat[i][l])-(sigma[k][l]+tau[k][l])*np.log(1+dat[i][l])) + exp_gamma[k]+  np.sum(exp_gamma_minus[:-1]))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code directly, not as an image.

Comment: hi @kaya3 just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you're doing a lot of recompute.

```
M_ikl[i][k][l] = np.exp(
    one_minu_theta[i][l] * (
       F[k][l] + 
       (sigma[k][l]-1) * np.log(dat[i][l]) - 
       (sigma[k][l]+tau[k][l]) * np.log(1+dat[i][l])
     ) + 
     exp_gamma[k] + 
     np.sum(exp_gamma_minus[:-1])
)
```

You'd want to avoid performing the logs and sums in the core of your algorithm

```
log_dat = np.log(dat)
log_dat_p1 = np.log(1+dat)
sum_gamma = np.sum(exp_gamma_minus[:-1])

for ... :
    M_ikl[i][k][l] = np.exp(
        one_minu_theta[i][l] * (
           F[k][l] + 
           (sigma[k][l]-1) * log_dat[i][l] - 
           (sigma[k][l]+tau[k][l]) * logdat_p1[i][l]
         ) + 
         exp_gamma[k] + 
         sum_gamma
    )
```

Next I'd consider doing the exponential at the end, outside the loop.

```
for ... :
    lnM_ikl[i][k][l] = 
        one_minus_theta[i][l] * (
           F[k][l] + 
           (sigma[k][l]-1) * log_dat[i][l] - 
           (sigma[k][l]+tau[k][l]) * logdat_p1[i][l]
         ) + 
         exp_gamma[k] + 
         sum_gamma

M = np.exp(lnM_ikl)
```

(I think your sum_gamma term is wrong, as it depends on k in the equation, but does not depend on k in your implementation - I'm just going to keep assuming it's OK)

Now you could try to split this up to use numpys distribution and tensor products etc.
But I think its now simple enough that  creating a small numba function should get you a very fast result.

```
@numba
def calc_log_M(one_minus_theta, F, sigma, log_dat, logdat_p1, exp_gamma, sum_gamma):
   lnM = np.zeros(...)
   for ... :
      lnM[i][k][l] = 
        one_minus_theta[i][l] * (
           F[k][l] + 
           (sigma[k][l]-1) * log_dat[i][l] - 
           (sigma[k][l]+tau[k][l]) * logdat_p1[i][l]
         ) + 
         exp_gamma[k] + 
         sum_gamma
   return lnM

log_dat = np.log(dat)
log_dat_p1 = np.log(1+dat)
sum_gamma = np.sum(exp_gamma_minus[:-1])

M = np.exp(calc_log_M(one_minus_theta, F, sigma, log_dat, logdat_p1, exp_gamma, sum_gamma))
```

You may need to tweak the numba parameters to get optimal performance out of this.